# what is the definition of a "change" in vim in terms of undo?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to understand multi-level undo in vim.
I opened vim and typed:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

and then I typed:

```
:u 1
```

I got message:

```
0 changes; before #1  22:53:11
```

and when I typed:

```
:u 2
```

I saw:

```
E830: Undo number 2 not found
```

my understanding is every vi command or character typed in edit mode is counted as a "change" but obvious that is not the case.

Could any seasoned vim expert clarify?

Comment: Every Vi (or Ex) command, sure, but not every character typed; that would be very tedious. As far as insertion goes, it is handled just as any other Vi command: you went into insert mode to insert something and go back to normal mode, that entire insert action is considered one undo step. (That said, I don’t really want to answer as I’m not sure that’s the end of it. I’m pretty sure there’s a bunch of complicating cases, e.g. when using a plugin that injects keypresses with `feedkeys`, and I’m not sure what happens then.)

Comment: thanks for the information. your explaination was helpful.

Comment: That's a good practical approximation.  It's pretty complicated beyond that, and it isn't particularly useful to understand if you're not a Vim developer.  The [gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim) can give you a feeling about the exact differences, and it's an excellent tool by itself.

Comment: thanks. gundo seems to do the same job as the :undol command.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a single change is every normal mode command that changes your buffer.

For insert mode, everything typed is considered a single change, until you leave insert mode. There are exceptions however. Using the cursor keys breaks the undo sequence. Another exception is, if you press <kbd>Ctrl+g</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> which will intentionally break the undo sequence. Also when temporarily leaving insert mode using e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+o</kbd> this will break a change.

Comment: thanks for the information. but, none of  the 3 exceptions you mentioned seemed to break the changes. after performing any of the 3 operations, I can still undo and redo as before.

Comment: Please be exact. What does not work, what do you expect? In the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_undo_branches) I also wrote how the changes are broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify undo behavior like this (in your `~/.vimrc`):

```
inoremap <BS> <c-g>u<BS>
inoremap <CR> <c-g>u<CR>
inoremap <del> <c-g>u<del>
inoremap <c-w> <c-g>u<c-w>
```

For more information see: `:h i_Ctrl-g_u` and read this link on [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modified_undo_behavior).

If you are using some completion plugin like me, you have to make more than that. I am using [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) and in this case I had to do this:

```
" <CR>: close popup and save indent.
" Now each Enter creates a undo point ":h i_Ctrl-g_u"
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>my_cr_function()<CR>
function! s:my_cr_function()
  return deoplete#mappings#smart_close_popup() . "\<C-g>u\<CR>"
endfunction
```